# Custom exception mapping in web xml does not work

Tags: jsf, exception, custom-error-pages

I have in my JSF 2.2 webapp a custom exception mapping in web.xml as below.

```
    <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">

    <display-name>Project</display-name>

    <!-- Welcome page -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <session-config>
       <!-- some codes-->
    </session-config>

    <error-page>
        <exception-type>se.telenor.ocfd.service.api.exception.CustomNotFoundException</exception-type>
        <location>/not_found.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/404.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>

    <error-page>
        <location>/500.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>

    <error-page>
        <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
        <location>/session_timeout.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>

</web-app>
```

My Exception is

```
@ApplicationException
public class CustomNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public CustomNotFoundException(String message, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
    }

    public CustomNotFoundException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

But it does `not redirect me to not_found.xhtml` page but instead `always redirect to 500.xhtml` page when the exception happens.

Can some one help me if any thing missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That can happen if the exception is wrapped in another exception, e.g. [`FacesException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/FacesException.html) or [`ELException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/el/ELException.html), depending on who was the first to catch the actual exception and delegating it further to the caller in wrapped form. This would then only match an `<error-page>` with exactly the given `<exception-type>` of `FacesException` or `ELException`.

One way to solve it is creating a [servlet filter](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info) which does something like below in `doFilter()` method:

```
try {
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
catch (ServletException e) {
    Throwable cause = e.getRootCause();

    if (cause instanceof FacesException || cause instanceof ELException) {
        throw new ServletException(cause.getCause()); // Unwrap and rethrow it.
    }
    else {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Map it to the `FacesServlet` or perhaps application wide via an URL pattern of `/*`.

If you happen to use JSF utility library [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org), a ready to use solution is available as [`FacesExceptionFilter`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/filters/FacesExceptionFilter).